# Connect to 3G internet connection (shared by iPhone) while connected to local network (wifi) without internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, osx-lion, iphone

Currently I need to connect to a local network that doesn't has any internet connection

Let's say this is the rough idea of this local network:

```
    router: 192.168.1.1
computer a: 192.168.1.2
computer b: 192.168.1.3
...
computer n: 192.168.1.x
my computer's IP in this network: 192.168.1.23
```

Since I need an internet connection, I try to share my iPhone's 3G connection to my computer. After that, what happened is my computer got 2 IPs (first one is the one that I got from the DHCP of the wifi network, the other one is my computer ip to connect to my iPhone).

The problem is, I can't browse anything or connect to the internet after I come to this state (2 IP addresses). Tt seems my computer always tries to find internet connection through the local network wifi instead of my 3G.

Can I get my computer connected to this local network through wifi while using the internet connection through my iPhone 3G connection?

The iPhone 3G connection is shared via Personal Hotspot.

Btw, my computer is OS X 10.7, hope can get some configuration that I can use in this os.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old thread, so perhaps you've already found a solution.
Personally, I've found sucess by tethering my phone to my computer via usb instead of setting up a hotspot.

My network configuration looks like this:

```
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:22:fb:b7:27:44 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.175/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlan0
    inet6 fe80::222:fbff:feb7:2744/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 
11: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:64:71:76:7d:72 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.42.101/24 brd 192.168.42.255 scope global usb0
    inet6 fe80::64:71ff:fe76:7d72/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I'm able to browse the internet normally, and also have access to my LAN.